# How to get input values from javascript function to save them into DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
function myFunction(y)
{

var f = y.parentNode;
var d = f.parentNode;
var g = d.parentNode;
var c =g.parentNode.rowIndex;   


var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var row = table.insertRow(c+1);


var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);

cell1.innerHTML = "<input type=text name='txt_id' id='id_id' size=10 placeholder=Id>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<input type=text name='txt_item' id='id_item' size=10    placeholder=Item>";
cell3.innerHTML = "<input type=text name='txt_cost' id='id_cost' size=10 placeholder=0.00>";
cell4.innerHTML = "<input type=text name='txt_wp' id='id_wp' size=10 placeholder=0.00>";
cell5.innerHTML = "<input type=text name='txt_rp' id='id_rp' size=10 placeholder=0.00>";

cell6.innerHTML = "<input type='button' name='submit' id='id_submitBtn' value='Save' size=10 onclick='form_submit()' >";


document.getElementById("myTable");

}
```

this is my code to add dynamic rows on a table when click on the add button. Now i need to get the values entered into the text boxes and submit to DB.

```
form_submit()
{
}
```

Is that possible by writing any code inside this function ?

Comment: use AjAx for passing data to server side ,and server side wil save Data

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird Thanks a lot for your time.But since i'm a beginner , i'm not that much familiar with ajax and al. Can you please help by the correct code that makes my above code work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the all values in array using :

```
$('#myTable input:text')
  .map(function() {return this.value;})
   .get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..but since i'm a beginner i don't understand how to use this code to obtain all those datas and where to write the insert query to insert those datas into DB. Can you please explain so that your code will make my above  code work ?

Comment: This will return the array of text values from text boxes. You need to make some server side call(using ajax) which saves the data in DB using queries.

Comment: "You need to make some server side call(using ajax) " , can you help me with this please..? i'm totally a beginner in this.. :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
form_submit()
{
    if ( validation is true ) {
        $.ajax({

            url:submit.php,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id : $("#id_id").val(),
                .
                .
                .
            },
            success: function () {
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i copied this code and pasted just below my code i've written above, then i wrote the missing code that u've indicated by dots..but finally when i click on the button of my newly generated dynamic row, it dosen't made any change. :( can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

After submiting form,
Use following:

```
var values = [];
$('#customTable input:text').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});

$.ajax({

        url:index.php,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
        valOfItems:values 
        }
        //Your custom operations like success,error etc
      });
```